# Export all contacts to VCF (vcard) file Windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone, vcf-vcard

I want to export phone book contacts to single VCF file. I'm new to VCF file.

I can't find any API or code to generate VCF file in Windows Phone.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can get VCF by using `ToVcardAsync` or `ToVcardAsync(VCardFormat)` methods.
`ContactInformation` class contains these methods.